If Apollo 13 had skipped off the atmosphere into space, and fell back down days later, what would have happened?

There's no way they could have planned a contingency for this. Nixon probably would have used the same speech prepared for the 11 guys dying on the moon.

Would the astronauts have said goodbye to their wives on a secure channel, knowing they'd slowly die within hours of horrible suffocation from CO2?

It's too horrible to think about. Excess CO2 in the blood makes mammals panic. If you've ever had Covid or been strangled into unconsciousness, you know the unspeakable horror.

So knowing they were going to die immediately, would they have opened a valve or  blown the explosive bolts; or would they suffocate to death thrashing in panic?

The reason I think about this is because  it would have happened if the entry angle had been off by half a degree, yet it's too horrible to think about.

There is no way Apollo 13 could have skipped into a solar orbit.
An orbit is, in some ways, like a pendulum. You can't ever swing higher than you started without adding energy in some way. Apollo 13 started its return from a point high over the far side of the moon. It could not gain enough energy on the way 'down' to bounce back up even higher/faster and escape; that would be like a pendulum swinging higher and higher with every swing. And even on a "skip", Apollo wouldn't have the energy it started with; atmospheric interface would steal energy from it.
Since Apollo 13 could not have escaped to solar orbit and had its periapsis inside the atmosphere (meaning it has to inevitably return to that point), it would have eventually reentered. It would have been long after the capsule ran out of air, yes, but it would've come home sooner or later.
That said, I think you have your order of operations confused. The SM and LM were not carried into the atmosphere. First they ditched the SM and got pictures of its damaged side (the only time they could have done so), still using the LM's remaining air and power until just about the last minute (and briefly having the vessel in a configuration never planned for, of the LM and capsule without a SM). At that point, they powered up reentry capsule, buttoned down the hatch, and blew the LM bolts. If a "skip" had happened, it would have been just the reentry capsule with no extra equipment. If they'd decided to space themselves to avoid slow suffocation, they maybe could have opened the side door, but the SM and LM would have been long gone by that point.

Wow you're right! What a wonderful answer! It fell from the moon, so it could had never get any higher than the moon, which is already captured by the Earth. But mainly, the fact that I overlooked that the CM/LM would have already been separated. I'm gonna leave it in there just because your pointing that out was so cool.

Apollo 13 had not done a free return trajectory, if they had missed the atmosphere entirly due navigation issues is it possible to math out how long the orbit period would have been?

@GremlinWranger Yeah, but by Darthpseudonym's reasoning, they can never fall fast enough to escape. The time to fall back down to Earth would be about 3 days — a little less than the time it took them to fall from the moon (because the moon wouldn't be dragging them back this time).

If that had happened, and the capsule entered in a random orientation, would it automatically orient itself heat shield forward? I must know!

@GremlinWranger I'm not sure I understand the question. Apollo 13 did use a free-return trajectory, they fired the LM thruster for a 16 ft/sec adjustment about 5 hours after the explosion to make that happen. But if they had missed the atmosphere entirely, I would think the orbit would be the same length as they started with from the far side of the moon, so... 65 hours one way, or 130 hours per orbit, give or take?

@MissUnderstands In theory, reentry capsules are self-righting, so it should have automatically put the heatshield forward, but the power would have run out long ago, so the chute sequencer would've been dead and it would hit the water or ground going quite fast.

Actually, I'm not totally sure the astronauts could open the side hatch in space. It opened outward, but maybe in the same way an airliner's door works, where it has to come in slightly before it can swing out, thus making the interior pressure a guard against accidental opening. I'm sure somebody else here will know the exact mechanics of the door they put on after Apollo 1.

Yes, @DarthPseudonym that's the kind of stuff I'm curious about. In fact, I'm wondering if it would be possible for them to vent the air at all, unless there was a way to equalize the pressure on the ocean. I know those fun loving Russians had an equalization valve on Soyuz with a bathroom sink knob on it, which led to their suffocation during reent.

@DarthPseudonym Yes, that's a very good point! The drogue chute mortars would still be disabled and the capsule would hit the water straight down at 100 miles an hour. It would have been smashed into little pieces.

@DarthPseudonym Internal pressure is less than 1 atmosphere though, certainly that's not enough to stop three grown men from opening a door.

@Cadence You think 3 men can open a door at one atmosphere with a vacuum on the other side? Mmmm... no way. Ask the airlines. 3 men can't even pull a (large) suction cup off a flat surface.

@Cadence The Apollo capsule was running at ~5 psi and the hatch was ~2.5 ft by ~3.5 ft, which is over 1200 square inches, for a total outward force of around 3 tons. I don't see three guys being able to shift that even a little.

@DarthPseudonym I've made a minor edit because I think CM and SM got confused in your last paragraph; commenting for extra visibility in case I am the confused one

not only do the Block 2 CM doors include a pressure equalization valve, I don't think the Block 2 CM side hatches were plug doors at all based on photos so interior pressure difference only would have aided them opening if the latches were disengaged.  Apollo 1 had an outer hatch and an inner plug door, as shown uncited here, but that was deleted to simplify egress

I'd like to note that Apollo-13 performed a burn 2 hours after lunar flyby, to speed up its return by 12 hours. But I can't find the delta v of the burn, and could it potentially make them heliocentric if they missed the atmosphere..

@ErinAnne No, you're right, I said the wrong letter, the result of rewriting that bit too many times!

@Heopps Hmm... PC+2 was about 262.6 m/s according to NASA's extremely useful Apollo 13 Flight Journal https://www.nasa.gov/history/afj/ap13fj/13day4-leaving-moon.html (see the notes just before 78:00) I don't THINK that would be enough to make them heliocentric but I guess I can't swear to it without a simulation. (And it does break the 'pendulum' analogy, though I still think a skip would have lost enough energy in the atmosphere to make them firmly geocentric.)
